# Convergence of operator in norm resolvent sense and their eigenvectors

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, operator-theory, unbounded-operators

Let $\{T_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ and $T$ be (unbounded) self-adjoint operators  and $T_n\to T$ in norm resolvent sense, that is, for some $z\in \mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{R}$, $\|(zI- T_n)^{-1}- (zI- T)^{-1}  \|\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$.

It is known that if the spectra $\sigma(T_n), n\in \mathbb{N}$, and $\sigma(T)$ are discrete then $\{T_n\}$ is spectrally exact for $T$ (that is, if $\lambda_n\to \lambda$ with $\lambda_n\in \sigma(T_n)$, then $\lambda\in \sigma(T)$ and if $\lambda\in \sigma(T)$, then there exists a sequence $\{\lambda_n\}$ with $\lambda_n\in \sigma(T_n)$ for which $\lambda_n\to \lambda$).

In a talk, someone pointed out that with the above assumptions of norm resolvent convergence and discrete spectra, the corresponding eigenvectors of $T_n$ converge to eigenvectors of $T$. I would like to know if I misunderstood or missed any point in this comment and if it is true, can someone please provide a proof or reference for the same? Also, are there any other sufficient conditions on $\{T_n\}$ for convergence of their eigenvectors?

Any help regarding this would be very much appreciated.

Comment: This sounds right, and one way to see it is to represent the spectral projections $E(\{\lambda\})$ as a contour integral of the resolvent: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1022232/contour-integration-of-resolvent